# How to Create Synapse workspace in sandbox?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-synapse

I am new to azure portal want to try Azure Synapse workspace. I dont want 12month free subscription. I use sandbox subscription to try various features.
But when i want to try Synapse workspace i get following error.

How to solve that?

```
"additionalInfo": [
{
  "type": "PolicyViolation",
  "info": {
    "policyDefinitionDisplayName": "Allowed resource types",
    "policySetDefinitionDisplayName": "webapps-initiative",
    "evaluationDetails": {
      "evaluatedExpressions": [
        {
          "result": "False",
          "expressionKind": "Field",
          "expression": "type",
          "path": "type",
          "expressionValue": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces",
          "targetValue": [
            "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
            "Microsoft.AlertsManagement/SmartDetectorAlertRules",
            "Microsoft.Cache/Redis",
            "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles",
            "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints",
            "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
            "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
            "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/webhooks",
            "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers",
            "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/serversv2",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
            "microsoft.insights/actiongroups",
            "microsoft.insights/components",
            "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "Microsoft.MixedReality/remoteRenderingAccounts",
            "Microsoft.Network/connections",
            "Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways",
            "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles",
            "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways",
            "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
            "Microsoft.Relay/namespaces",
            "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationrules",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationrules",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/authorizationrules",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
            "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules",
            "Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR",
            "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
            "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
            "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms",
            "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/workers",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/instances",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/metricdefinitions",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/metrics",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/instances",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/metricdefinitions",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/metrics",
            "Microsoft.Web/staticSites"
          ],
          "operator": "In"
        }
      ]
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/a08ec900-254a-4555-9bf5-e42af04b5c5c",
    "policySetDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/learn-sandbox-prod/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/webapps-initiative",
    "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "allowed-resource-types_1",
    "policySetDefinitionName": "webapps-initiative",
    "policyDefinitionName": "a08ec900-254a-4555-9bf5-e42af04b5c5c",
    "policyDefinitionEffect": "deny",
    "policyAssignmentId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/192fe359-e72a-fa7e-dcd5-95e985e7eac9/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/webapps-assignment",
    "policyAssignmentName": "webapps-assignment",
    "policyAssignmentScope": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/192fe359-e72a-fa7e-dcd5-95e985e7eac9"
  }
}
]
```

Which model sandbox should i use to resolve this error. I just want to learn Azure Synapse Analytics for my dp203 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, there is no sandbox environment for Azure Synapse Analytics.

**Reason:** With MS Learn sandbox subscription, you can't create all type of resources but just the resource which you are allowed in learning path you are going through.

You need to create a [free trial account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/synapse-analytics/) for learning Azure Synapse Analytics.

Comment: Always the free trial there is.